# Does every element of the weak-star closure of a set belong to the weak-star closure of a bounded subset?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I feel like this must be a monumentally stupid question. Say $X$ is a Banach space, $S\subset X^*$, and $x^*$ is in the weak* closure of $S$. Must $x^*$ lie in the weak* closure of some norm-bounded subset of $S$?

(If $x^*$ is the weak* limit of a sequence of elements of $S$ then this is clear by Banach-Steinhaus. But a convergent *net* of scalars need not be bounded...)

Comment: The question does not ask whether this subset may depend on $x^*$.

Comment: If $B$ is a closed ball of $X^*$ containing $x^*$, then $B$ is weakly* closed and norm-bounded. Maybe you can consider $S \cap B$?

Comment: Yes, I know that a closed ball is weak* closed - in fact it's weak* compact. I haven't seen how that helps. Your comment that I don't specify whether the subset may depend on $x^*$ makes very little sense to me, sorry. $S$ and $x^*$ are _given_.

Comment: if I understood well the definitions, $X^*$ is a normed vector space for the operator norm. for any $y \in X^*$ : $\|y\|_{X^*}= \max_{\textstyle x \in X, \|x\|_X \le 1} |y(x)|$, and it is a Banach space since $X$ is complete. the weak closure $\overline{S}$ of $S \subset X^*$  is $s \in \bar{S}$ iff there is a sequence $(s_n) \in S$ such that for every $x \in X$ : $|s(x) - s_n(x)| \to 0$. but this doesn't ensure that $s \in X^*$ i.e. that $\|s\|_{X^*} < \infty$ ?

Comment: or maybe I didn't understand what was the weak* closure ?

Comment: @user1952009 I guess so. ;-)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : very funny... so, what means $s \in \bar{S}$ the weak* closure of $S \in X^*$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 The biggest problem with your comment is the word "sequence". The weak* topology is not metrizable.

Comment: a closure is always adding the limits of some "so said converging" sequences... ?

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, but why don't you just google it?

Comment: @user1952009 No, that is simply not true.

Comment: @user1952009 +1 for wishing us fun. ;-)

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, but it sounds like you simply don't understand the difference between a topologicall space and a metric space, and that's a long story...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : when reading wikipedia, I have the feeling it says what I wrote... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak-.2A_convergence

Comment: @user1952009 This is getting a little tedious. It does not say what you wrote. That bit on Wikipedia refers to _nets_, not sequences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Krein-Smulian theorem](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/bs-5.pdf) says that for a **convex** set $S$, having weak*-closed intersections with closed balls implies being weak*-closed. The fact that convexity is required here suggests that the answer to your question should be negative.  And it is.

Let $X=\ell^2$. In the dual space, also $\ell^2$, consider the "infinite ellipsoid" 
$$
S = \left\{y : \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n^2/n^2=1\right\}
$$
Every line through the origin meets $S$; therefore, $0$ is in the weak closure of $S$.

On the other hand, $0$ is not in the weak closure of any intersection $S\cap B_R$ where $B_R=\{y:\|y\|\le R\}$. Indeed, consider the weak-open sets 
$$
U_N = \left\{y: \sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2 < \frac12\right\}
$$
If $N$ is large enough, then for every $y\in U_N\cap B_R $ we have 
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n^2/n^2 < \frac12+ \frac{R^2}{(N+1)^2} < 1
$$
hence $U_N\cap (B_R\cap S)= \varnothing$.

Comment: Excellent - my $S$ actually is convex, so Krein-Smulllyan is just what I needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Lol, why didn't you say this before... ;-)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Sorry. Should have realized convexity could be relevant. Heh, I _said_ it must be a stupid question, just a little stupider than I thought.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich As 404's answer shows, it's not that stupid. And I just realized that you might not have seen that convexity plays a role. So, why should you have mentioned it. Maybe you did not even check your set for convexity before. I admit I had forgotten about Krein-Shmulyan, but I knew that weak closure and norm-closure of convex sets are the same. So, I thought $S$ should probably not be convex for a counterexample. However, have fun applying Krein-Shmulyan. :-)

Comment: @404: Can you please explain your sentence: "Every line through the origin meets $S$; therefore, $0$ is in the weak closure of $S$."? The unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ also has this property, but $0$ is not in its weak(*) closure.

Comment: @gerw Every weak neighborhood of 0 in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space contains a iine (since it contains a subspace of finite codimension).

Comment: @404: Of course! -- and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not infinite dimensional ;)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer by 404, I have two further counterexamples in $\ell^2$:
\begin{align*}
A &= \{ \sqrt{n} \, e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \\
B &= \{ e_m + m \, e_n : m,n \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \le m < n \}
\end{align*}
Again, $0$ is in the weak* closure, but all intersections of $A$ or $B$ with bounded sets are discrete! (It is also interesting to note that this implies that there is no sequence in $A$ or $B$ converging weak*ly to $0$.)

Answer (score 1):

The reference to Krein-Smulian in one of the answers is actually a little misleading, and is related to the following warning in [Conway's Functional Analysis](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_Course_in_Functional_Analysis.html?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&redir_esc=y), page 161:

[image: page 161]

In fact, you can find a Banach space $X$ and $S\subseteq X^\ast$ a subspace (so certainly convex) such that $S$ is weak$^*$-dense in $X^\ast$, but there is a vector $f_0\in X^\ast$ such that no *bounded* net in $S$ converges to $f_0$; equivalently, $f_0$ is not in the weak$^\ast$-closure of $S$ intersected with any bounded subset of $X^\ast$.

I do not know a canonical reference for a construction.  However, it is fairly easy to adapt [this Mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/102411).  I wrote up the details [here (github)](https://github.com/MatthewDaws/Mathematics/tree/master/Kaplansky2).